# Why does the position of the verb vary?

Tags: word-order

Why is the verb not consistently in the 2nd position in these sentences?

> So weit ich **weiß**.

> So weit das Auge **reicht**.

> So weit ich zurückdenken **kann**.

> So weit **reichen** meine Fähigkeiten nicht.

> So weit **reichen** meine Beziehungen nicht

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first 3 examples are no full sentences, there has to be something additional
[except the first one when someone asks sth. "Weiß er darüber Bescheid?" - "so weit ich weiß (schon / ,ja)"]

- Das stimmt, so weit ich weiß.
- Blauer Himmel, so weit das Auge reicht.
- Ich versuche mich zu erinnern, so weit ich zurückdenken kann.

That is also possible with the 4. and 5. example:

- Ich erfülle die Aufgabe, so weit meine Fähigkeiten reichen.
- Ich setze mich für dich ein, so weit meine Beziehungen reichen.

Also (if that is interesting to you) you can change the word order in the type of sentence as examples 4 and 5 are:

- Meine Fähigkeiten reichen (nicht) so weit.
- Meine Beziehungen reichen (nicht) so weit.

The 3rd example can be changed aswell (the others would sound strange that way):

- Ich kann (nicht) so weit zurückdenken. / So weit kann ich (nicht) zurückdenken.

As a native German speaker I only can tell you that, I don't know the rule, but I also think that this is that kind of thing, which one better learns by reading a lot :)
And asking natives :D

Comment: Thank you for joining in and help us to learn.

Comment: "*Blauer Himmel.*" is not a full sentence either, make it "*Der Himmel ist blau, …*". And not only the first one can be an answer to a question.

Comment: @Bergi it's a common phrase

Answer (score 6):

The first three are not main clauses (Hauptsätze) but dependent clauses (Nebensätze) for which the respective main clauses are missing. I don't know where you found these, but they could for example be later additions to earlier main clauses.

> Die Files sind inzwischen gelöscht. *(pause)* Soweit ich weiß.

The *Nebensätze* use [the conjunction "so weit"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/soweit#1). The *Hauptsätze* use the [adverb "so weit"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/soweit#2). An alternative spelling for both is  "soweit".